# How to configure network for Windows server running in Virtualbox

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, virtualbox, linux-networking

I have dedicated server (OVH) running Debian 6.0. As it is pretty powerful machine and it's not fully utilized, I want to try and run Windows server on it using Virtualbox. I've already installed Virtualbox and Windows Server 2008 R2. The last thing to do is to configure the network, and that I really don't know how to do.

IP address of my server is 176.31.xxx.xxx, and I've bought another IP 87.98.xxx.xxx that is routed to my original IP address (176.31.xxx.xxx). How can I configure the host and the client OS so that the host is still accessible via 176.31.xxx.xxx IP, and the client (Windows) is using 87.98.xxx.xxx IP address?

Answer (score 1):

NAT is not an option for Adapter Type.

Click where it currently says Bridged Adapter and you should be able to select NAT.

Check below link

```
  http://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/configure-the-virtualbox-network-2/
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up "[Host-only](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)" network interface on the guest, and you will get an interface on the host, and an interface on the guest which are (virtually) connected.

Then set up IPs and routes on both systems, and enable IP forwarding on your host.

Comment: Can you help me out a little more? I've created host-only network. Now I have vboxnet0 interface in Linux and Intel interface in windows. What's the next step? Which IP address do I give to vboxnet0 and which to Intel interface? How do I setup the routes?